# Flask / Werkzeug run_simple not displaying Exception traces

Tags: flask, werkzeug, flask-restful

I created two flask apps: frontend and restapi (with flask-restful). I created the following runserver.py to run them in development:

```
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple

from restapi import app as restapi_app
from frontend import app as frontend_app

application = DispatcherMiddleware(frontend_app, {
  '/api': restapi_app,
})

if __name__ == "__main__":
  run_simple(
    'localhost',
    5000,
    application,
    use_reloader=True,
    use_debugger=True,
    use_evalex=True)
```

Despite having use_debugger=True, whenever one of the flask-restful resources raises an error, I don't get a trace, just a 500 error

```
{"status": 500, "message": "Internal Server Error"}
```

Any ideas how to get the full trace to display? Let me know if you need more details/code.

Comment: Just a guess, but you probably need to set `DEBUG` to `True` for both app objects.

Comment: That was it! Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`use_debugger` option of Werkzeug WSGI server only enables embedded debugger, the server is unaware of Flask app configuration values (`DEBUG` in this case). To propagate exceptions to the server, you need to enable debug mode for both Flask app objects yourself. Here's one way to do it:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    restapi_app.debug = True
    frontend_app.debug = True
    run_simple(...)
```